# Printing row and columns in reverse

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please help, ive been battling with this for ages. I have a code:

```
contents =[     
        [0, 3, 1, 1, 6, 3, 7, 5, 2, 4, 1],
        [0, 3, 4, 5, 11, 14, 21, 26, 28, 32, 33],
        [4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 5, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 5],
        [0, 4, 6, 9, 11, 14, 21, 26, 30, 35, 38],
        [4, 6, 9, 11, 14, 18, 23, 30, 35, 38, 42],
        [4, 3, 5, 6, 3, 4, 2, 4, 7, 6, 9],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0],
    ]
```

and i want to print it like for example:
code is:

```
alpha = [
    ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
    ["f", "g", "h", "i", "j"],
    ["k", "l", "m", "n", "o"],
]
```

result should look like:

```
["a", "f", "k"] 
["b", "g", "l"] 
["c", "h", "m"] 
["d", "i", "n"] 
["e", "j", "o"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easily achieved with a `zip`.

```
for row in zip(*contents):
    print(row)
```

This prints:

```
(0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0)
(3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 3, 0)
(1, 4, 3, 2, 6, 9, 5, 0)
(1, 5, 2, 4, 9, 11, 6, 0)
(6, 11, 3, 0, 11, 14, 3, 0)
(3, 14, 4, 0, 14, 18, 4, 0)
(7, 21, 2, 0, 21, 23, 2, 3)
(5, 26, 4, 0, 26, 30, 4, 3)
(2, 28, 5, 2, 30, 35, 7, 0)
(4, 32, 3, 3, 35, 38, 6, 0)
(1, 33, 4, 5, 38, 42, 9, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. you are a life, time and energy saver

Comment: Glad to help.  Consider accepting this answer to let other people know that this was helpful for you.